# Where did the paper Hanzo come from?

Tags: kubo-and-the-two-strings

In the film, Kubo is assisted by a paper samurai, apparently a representation of his deceased father, Hanzo. Originally, Kubo believes that the samurai was sent by his father from beyond the grave.

However, we later find out that Hanzo

> isn't actually dead, merely cursed to be a beetle and suffering from memory loss.

This raises the question of where the paper figure came from. Hanzo didn't create it, and it seems unlikely that either Kubo or his mother did, as the samurai knew things that neither of them could have, such as the location of legendary sword.

**So who sent it?**

Comment: We need more Kubo questions. I've treated myself to the [junior novel](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Kubo-Two-Strings-Junior-Novel/dp/0316361445) and the "[Art of](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Art-Kubo-Two-Strings/dp/1452153159)" books.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No-one *sent* Little Hanzo. He/it was a creation of Kubo and his mother's magic, **combined with her knowledge of the location of the various pieces of armour** at the Long Lake, the Skull Statue and in the Village.

Notably, the mother is suffering from memory lapses both prior to her becoming a

> monkey

and afterwards. Although she professes not to know where the armour is, it's pretty clear that she was *well on the trail of it*, given that she was capable of warning Beetle about the dangers of the Long Lake and had settled Kubo in the very village...

> ...where the Helmet Invulnerable was hidden.

---

As to precisely how Little Hanzo was able to translate her *subconscious* knowledge of the Armour's location into *actual direction-finding* (complete with pointing), I think we can assume that that's where the magic comes in.